# Is the relation $5$ divides $(x-y)$ an equivalence relation on $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Is the relation $5$ divides $(x-y)$ an equivalence relation on $\mathbb Z$?

Can someone helps me out with this question? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the properties that must hold for equivalence relations? Can you translate those properties into this context?

Comment: So, for a relation to be called an equivalence relation, it's customary to have three specific requirements. Have you checked any of them?

Comment: You mean the reflexivity, symmetricity and transitivity?

Comment: Actually I have done the question and my answer is the relation is equivalence relation on Z.As for reflexivity, I could have(5,5),(6,6)...For symmetricity, I can have (1,6),(6,1)... and for transitivity, I could have(1,6).(6,11),(1,11)....Is my way of proofing this correct?

Comment: @HanyiKoh That looks like a very good start. Although you've only proven it for very specific special cases (namely 1, 6 and 11). Your proofs need to cover _all possible_ cases.